# How to remove duplicates in a frequency table?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am a beginner to coding and have produced a code which counts the frequency of words and then puts into a table using panda package, but I need to remove the duplicates produced.

I have followed online tutorials of how to remove duplicates, but the current code still doesn't work, as can be seen in the second input. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

INPUT

```
  txt = "chilli mango chilli mango grape"
  words = txt.split()
  for word in words:
        print(word + " " + str(txt.count(word)))
  import pandas as pd
  mytable = pd.DataFrame()
  for word in words:
        tempdf = pd.DataFrame({"word" : [word], "frequency" : [txt.count(word)]})
        mytable = mytable.append(tempdf)
        print(mytable)
```

OUTPUT

```
 chilli 2
 mango 2
 chilli 2
 mango 2
 grape 1

 word  frequency
 0  chilli          2
 word  frequency
 0  chilli          2
 0   mango          2
 word  frequency
 0  chilli          2
 0   mango          2
 0  chilli          2
 word  frequency
 0  chilli          2
 0   mango          2
 0  chilli          2
 0   mango          2
 word  frequency
 0  chilli          2
 0   mango          2
 0  chilli          2
 0   mango          2
 0   grape          1
```

INPUT

```
data = mytable
data.sort_values("First name", inplace = True)
data.drop_duplicates(subset = "First name", 
                 keep = False, inplace = True)
print(data)
```

Comment: use normal dictionary - like `{word:  frequency}` - and it will replace item if you use existing `word`. And after `for-`loop use this dictionary to create `DataFrame`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the feedback. But would you be able to demonstrate the code I need after the next line, as I am confused of how to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collections.Counter` is also designed for this type of task, and can easily be converted into a pandas dataframe.

```
from collections import Counter
txt = "chilli mango chilli mango grape"
words = txt.split()
counts = Counter(words)  # Counter({'chilli': 2, 'grape': 1, 'mango': 2})
df = pd.DataFrame(counts.items(), columns=["Word", "Frequency"])  # same data as a dataframe
```

You could also build a dataframe like this to avoid creating duplicates:

```
mytable = pd.DataFrame(columns=["word", "frequency"]).set_index("word")
for word in words:
    if word in mytable.index:
        mytable.loc[word] += 1
    else:
        mytable.loc[word] = 1
```

Having said that your existing code should actually work if you drop the `keep = False` (which tells it to remove *all* duplicates, including the first copy) and change `"First name"`to `"word"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This was a great explanation for the alternative approach and the corrections to my existing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do a `dict`:

```
dct = {}
for word in txt.split():
    if word not in dct:
        dct[word] = 1
    else:
        dct[word] += 1

frequency = pd.Series(dct)
```

or `pandas` way:

```
frequency = pd.Series(txt.split()).value_counts()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. I'm not sure if I followed your advice right but I still have the duplicates. Could you write how the code should be after my last line?

Comment: The code is for the entire process, takes `txt` as input.

Comment: So your write --> txt = "chilli mango chilli mango grape" and then do your dict part or pandas way? Because I did that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: That'd be pretty surprising. Can you try this [live demo](https://repl.it/repls/FastGroundedMatter)?

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I was not importing pandas on the first line. Also just to develop my understanding of python, why did you put print ('_' *20) ? What does this line mean, in regards to the 20?

Comment: `'-'*20` means repeat `'-'` twenty times. I used it to separate the output from other stuff.